# How to factory reset and wipe clean a macbook pro with APFS filesystem?

Tags: disk-format, formatting, hdd

I have a Macbook pro with HD (not SSD) upgaded up to Big Sur. I formatted it and reinstalled BigSur (to be configured). I would like to clean all data (but keeping a boot option or OSX installation if possible) since it is going to change owner.

However, since it is APFS, I cannot securely format (i.e., writing random data, even more than once, and then reset to 0), as it was possible in macos extended journal.

I thought I could first factory reset, but I cannot even find a way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The best option in my opinion is to create a Big Sur install key : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

Then boot from it and with disk utility you erase the primary disk.

To be able to select it cmd + 2 then you select the HDD then "Erase" and you choose APFS format and GUID partition scheme. You validate and exit Disk Utility.

Then you install Big Sur without an iCloud account. You simply create an Admin account.

And that's all.

Comment: I'd do all of this, PLUS a secure erase run as HFS [if APFS won't allow it] during the format, as it's an HD. Far too easy to recover otherwise.

Comment: You can use the terminal from the top menu Utility withe the command : `diskutil zerodisk force diskX` replacing diskX by the good value disk0 generally for the internal disk.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution. I factory-resetted by pressing cmd+option+shift+R (instead of cmd+R), format to extended journal, reinstalled the old OSX and then reformatted securely.